# PayPal Payflow Link / PayflowPro Error Invalid Required Domain

Tags: paypal, payflowpro, payflowlink

I'm trying to integrate PayPal PayflowPro / PayflowLink within our system, and in testing everything is working as expected. When we switched over to live credentials, we are able to create a secure token, using the live merchant details; but when attempted to redirect to a hosted checkout page, we are receiving a new error, which we haven't seen before.

**Error invalid Required Domain**

We have searched for hours, with no reference in PayPal's official documentation or the internet. Can someone who has worked with PayPal, explain what this error means?

Willing to give up some rep to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your referrer URL, see if it is valid domain. 
They generally check if incoming host url is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

no idea if this is still an issue but I'm developing against the legacy payflow link and got this error.  It was easily fixed by logging in to paypal manager, going to service settings->payflow link and then entering your domain in the accepted URLs at the bottom of the page